# JavaScript Popup Chrome 'save as'-deactivated? Why?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, popup, window.open

I am opening an popup in Javascript with:

```
function popup(title,w,h,site) {
    x = screen.availWidth/2-w/2;
    y = screen.availHeight/2-h/2;

    var date = new Date()
    var ticks = date.getTime();

    var popupWindow = window.open(
        title,"popup"+ticks,'width='+w+',height='+h+',left='+x+',top='+y+',screenX='+x+',screenY='+y+',resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,toolbar=yes,titlebar=yes,hotkeys=yes,status=yes,dependent=no,location=1');
    popupWindow.document.write(site);
    return popupWindow;
  }
```

When I right click the new window, the "save as"-dialog is deactivated in chrome.

How can I enable it? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

the attribute `status` should be `1` not `yes`. This should be what is preventing Chrome from treating the popup as a new window.

Also, `open()` takes parameters in this order:

```
window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)
```

So try:

```
window.open("about:blank", title, 'width='+w+',height='+h+',left='+x+',top='+y+',screenX='+x+',screenY='+y+'resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,toolbar=yes,titlebar=yes,hotkeys=yes,status=yes,dependent=no,location=1')
```

Comment: also change `title` to `'about:blank'`

Comment: The `status` attribute is still `yes`, not `1` in the code snippet posted in this answer..? Neither one works for me anyway...did anyone figure this out? If not why is this answer accepted..?

Comment: Not sure why this answer was accepted because it doesn't solve the problem.