# 'Save As...' disabled in popup window

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I'm opening an html popup window in an ExtJS application and generating the CSS and content dynamically.  The popup is intended to reconfigure an existing panel to be print-friendly as well as save-able as html.  The print functionality works fine, but the 'Save As...' option is disabled in chrome and I can't figure out why.  The actual URL of the page doesn't exist since the content is being generated dynamically (it opens as about:blank) so I suppose that could be the problem.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
 var myWindow = window.open('', 'Transcript', 'x=10, width=' + w + ',height="80%",resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes' );

    myWindow.document.write('<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head>');
    myWindow.document.write('<title>' + 'Transcript' + '</title>');
     myWindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/custom.css">');
     myWindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/print.css">');
     myWindow.document.write('<script>function printPage() {  console.log(window.print()); }</script>');
    myWindow.document.write('<style>' + cssStylesheetContents + '</style>');
    myWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
     myWindow.document.write(title);
     myWindow.document.write('<div class="transcriptView">' + content + "</div>");
    myWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
     myWindow.document.close();
    myWindow.focus();
    myWindow.print();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416646/javascript-popup-chrome-save-as-deactivated-why might help

Comment: Nope, nothing in that thread is of any help